# Complex number plotting in python

Tags: python, text-editor, complex-numbers

I have an array of complex numbers. I copied that to a text file by using the following python script.

```
import csv
csvfile = "text_name.txt" 
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in filetomat:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

I got the result like this-

> (0.612751-0.112445j)
>   (0.453966+0.516774j)
>   (0.263492+1.02788j)
>   (0.223189+1.1474j)
>   (0.37237+0.812074j)
>   (0.620341+0.178921j)

How to remove the brackets for each value? I want to get result without brackets.

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just remove the brackets (but keep the `+` and the `j`), then you can format a string like this:

```
writer.writerow(["%f+%fj" % (d.real, d.imag)])
```

or if you want to keep the fields separate so they can be loaded more easily:

```
writer.writerow([d.real, d.imag])
```

The brackets just come from the default way in which complex numbers are converted into strings.

Comment: Got it. Thank You very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to accept this answer, if you wish.